# PHP Session gets destroyed on Subdomain

Tags: php, session, authentication, subdomain

I'm trying to create a login system for my website. I got the session thing all set up and stuff. The user stays logged in on www.myhomepage.tld and it is displayed correctly everywhere.

However, as soon as I try to access the session from anysubdomain.myhomepage.tld, it gets destroyed instantly. The login indicator does not say the user is logged in, and when I return to www.myhomepage.tld, the user is no longer logged in.

I have set up a global .php file that contains functions used by many pages. One of them starts the session.

```
function startsession() {
    session_name('login');
    session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", ".raptilic.us");
    session_start();
}
```

When I access a page on the subdomain that does not call this function or any other session function, the session stays alive. But as soon as I call it from any subdomain, the session is destroyed. Why? Do you know a fix?

The weird thing about it is not just that the session is inaccessible from the subdomain. The session is destroyed.

**EDIT**: It was a problem with some encryption thing. I solved the issue by putting

```
php_flag "suhosin.session.cryptdocroot" 0
```

into the .htaccess file.

Comment: where are you creating the session

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.raptilic.us' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: you can use cookies as follows  setcookie("ID", $id, $hour,"/", ".raptilic.us"); ... It will across the sub domain

Comment: I did `setcookie("ID", session_id(), 3600, "/", ".raptilic.us");`. Is that correct? It still doesn't work.

Comment: in sub domain check if (!isset($_COOKIE["ID"])) {
     //register session here... for sub domain...
}